# Can not find assembly file Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.dll error on .net core publish

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I can run the project locally in IISExpress successfully.  However when I try to publish the project to an IIS Server this is the error message I'm receiving.

Error: Can not find assembly file Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.dll ...

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a solution?
Here is my project.json file.

```
{
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
"EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
},

"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
}
},

"frameworks": {
"net461": {
  "dependencies": {
    "DomainModel": {
      "target": "project"
    },
    "Models": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  }
}
},

"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "Views",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
},

"scripts": {
"prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% -   -framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the version in the file global.json ?
I went in version "1.0.0-preview 2-003121" and that to correct the problem for me.

Comment: Overall, yes that seemed to be the issue.  I feel that the full release is still not as stable as we all hoped.

Comment: The choice of version of the libraries is somewhat capricious and unstable I think.
Let's wait and see time.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem by the workaround found in this post.  Looks like it was a problem with Entity Framework and working with the correct version that is compatible with .netcore1.

[Work Around Solution](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3742)

[image]